# Не приходит почта по smtp — gitlab. Куда копать?

Tags: smtp, gitlab

Имею такие настройки:

```
gitlab_rails['gitlab_email_from'] = 'git@myurl.ru'
gitlab_rails['gitlab_email_display_name'] = 'git@myurl.ru'

gitlab_rails['smtp_enable'] = true
gitlab_rails['smtp_address'] = "smtp.yandex.ru"
gitlab_rails['smtp_port'] = 587
gitlab_rails['smtp_user_name'] = "zzx.s@yandex.ru"
gitlab_rails['smtp_password'] = "pass"
gitlab_rails['smtp_domain'] = "myurl.ru"
gitlab_rails['smtp_authentication'] = "zzx.s@yandex.ru"
gitlab_rails['smtp_enable_starttls_auto'] = true
#gitlab_rails['smtp_tls'] = true
gitlab_rails['smtp_openssl_verify_mode'] = 'peer'
```

При восстановлении пароля ничего не происходит. Нужно ли какие-то порты открывать?

**UPDATE:** При попытке отправки тестового письма возникает ошибка:

```
ArgumentError: wrong authentication type zzx.s@yandex.ru
    from /opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/smtp.rb:772:in `check_auth_method'
    from /opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/smtp.rb:548:in `do_start'
    from /opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/smtp.rb:521:in `start'
    ...
```

Comment: В логах что-нибудь есть? Что произойдет если отправить тестовое сообщение: в консоли (`gitlab-rails console`) набрать `Notify.test_email('test@myurl.ru', 'Hello World', 'Hello World').deliver_now`?

Comment: В логах ничего не увидел. Но всё-таки уточню: какие логи смотреть? После отправки через консоль: http://rgho.st/download/private/6JGrN7cNL/a18e93f41b6207ba66c8da5abb9d2a7b/b98c997b2a303c684e0a503d5d5a013bd968f166/mailtext.txt (данные соответственно изменил на свои)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не уверен, что это решит проблему, но `smtp_authentication` это тип аутентификации, и заменять его на свой логин не нужно.

Попробуйте заменить параметр на:

```
gitlab_rails['smtp_authentication'] = "login"
```

Еще, в [примере настройки почты Яндекса](https://docs.gitlab.com/omnibus/settings/smtp.html#yandex) указан порт 465

```
gitlab_rails['smtp_port'] = 465
```

Comment: smtp_authentication изменил на login, потом вовсе закомментировал (#gitlab_rails['smtp_authentication'] = "login") - ничего не изменилось. На 465ый порт менять не имеет смысла, тк у яндекса TLS на 587ом, но попробовал - без изменений.

Comment: @Emia Жаль, видимо проблема где-то еще. Ошибка та же самая `Wrong authentication type` ?

Comment: Приношу извинения, сразу не проверил: Net::ReadTimeout: Net::ReadTimeout

Comment: @Emia обновите вопрос, укажите новую конфигурацию, внесенные изменения и полное сообщение об ошибке. В чем проблема сложно сказать, попробуйте раскомментировать `smtp_tls`

Comment: `smtp_tls` включен, ошибка: Net::SMTPFatalError: 553 5.7.1 Sender address rejected: not owned by auth user.

Comment: @Emia проверьте, что в `gitlab_email_from` и `gitlab_email_display_name` установлен тот же адрес что и в `smtp_user_name`. З.Ы. под текстом вопроса есть кнопка «править», с ее помощью можно внести изменения в вопрос

Comment: Благодарю. Почта начала приходить.